# Best way to approach statistics pages

Tags: layout, page-layout, statistics, stats

In general what is the best way to approach a statistics page. Not a dashboard, but a page showing a number of numerical stats with labels. Say for example, there are around 10 numerical stats that we want to show. How should hierarchy be determined when we are unsure of what data is most important? or maybe some data is important to some users but not others and we have no way of determining this until it has been in use for a while. We want the page to be aesthetically pleasing but at the same time functional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Say for example, there are around 10 numerical stats that we want to
>   show. How should hierarchy be determined when we are unsure of what
>   data is most important?

This must come from business. Unless you have domain expertise you cannot make any decisions.

I did mock-ups for a medical app.  Our team though it was organized well for a first draft. A domain expert came in, reviewed it and completely reorganized it. "Type of illness" (which we thought was of crucial importance) was unimportant but room number and time of admittance were very important.

Answer (score 0):

I completely agree with Mayo, particularly if the business is able to come up with the best hierarchy. Although if it's something that is likely to be different for each user then perhaps you can give the user the ability to set their own order.

I know you don't have a dashboard, but even a list of numerical stats with labels could be 'dragged and set' by the user, or ordered by changing settings in another page.

Basically I completely agree with Mayo, if it's an application for a certain type of user e.g. doctors. But I just want to also touch on the use case where each user may have different preferences and giving them the ability to set their own order might help.